# Magento 2.3.5: system.xml file upload allow types not working

Tags: image-upload, magento2.3.5

> **system.xml**

```
<field id="upload_image_id" translate="label comment" type="image" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Select Image</label>
   <backend_model>NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
   <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">yourfolder</base_url>
</field>
```

> **Image.php**

```
namespace NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
/**
 * The tail part of directory path for uploading
 *
 */
const UPLOAD_DIR = 'yourfolder'; // Folder save image

/**
 * Return path to directory for upload file
 *
 * @return string
 * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
protected function _getUploadDir()
{
    return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
}

/**
 * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
{
    return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
}
```

Still not allowing it I get `Disallowed file type.` Anything else missing ?

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Need to create virtualType in di.xml

Comment: Already created but give Disallowed file type error.

Answer (score 0):

> you can try with below code in system.xml file:
> system.xml

```
<field id="upload_image_id" translate="label comment" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
               <label>Select Image</label>
               <backend_model>NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
               <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">yourfolder</base_url>
</field>
```

Comment: Already tried with `type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image"` not working!

Comment: @JulianoVargas, please check this link https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-file-upload-sytem-configuration-magento-2.html. I hope it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: Yeah done that already as well. Doesn't work still! looked every possible blog out there but possible are outdated as i am on 2.3.5 and is fairly new version.

Comment: can you please try my ans and let me know  if you face any error

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your **system.xml** file

```
<field id="my_image_field" translate="label" sortOrder="1" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Image" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>My Image</label>
        <backend_model>Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
        <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">my_image_folder</base_url>
        <validate>required-entry</validate>
        <upload_dir config="system" scope_info="1">my_image_folder</upload_dir>
    </field>
```

now your **image.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
{
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }
}
```

Please note that the image will be saved in `magento_root/pub/media/my_image_folder`

Comment: Nope. not working !

Comment: can you please share what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `Disallowed file type`.  already checked the file type in File/Uploader `_validateFile` and is indeed `svg` when I upload.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is a combination of the answers from here and from Mageplaza blog.

```
<field id="my_image" type="Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\File" translate="true" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
    <label>Image</label>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Image</backend_model>
    <upload_dir config="system">my_custom_folder</upload_dir>
</field>
```

and in Image.php class:

```
<?php 
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config;

    class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File
    {
        protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
        {
            return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
        }
    }
```

And i can properly upload a file and when saving, i get the proper validation if i select a file with an extension other than the ones listed above:

[image]